# Can I inject something to jms:listener-container?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-jms

Can I inject some other bean to jms listener container defined using this tag:

```
<jms:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory">...</jms:listener-container>
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<jms:listener-container/>` is just a configuration convenience; it is not a bean in itself, it represents a set of attributes that will be applied to the child `<jms:listener/>` elements. Each listener gets its own listener container bean.

You can `reference` some other bean in the listener...

```
<jms:listener-container ... >
    <jms:listener destination="someQueue" ref="foo" />
</jms:listener-container>
```